# TFS2010 - Link to other work item embedded in text field?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

When entering a work item in TFS2010, it's often nice to refer to other tickets in the text free fields (either description or Acceptance Criteria field).
Most other ticket tracking software I have used automatically creates links/hyperlinks to other tickets if you put appropriate text into these fields (e.g, Trac, BugTracker.NET, etc).

I understand the link tab, and that you can create relationships there, but it would be lovely to have this feature available and clickable in the other text field.

Does TFS2010 (+ Visual Studio 2010) support something like this? I cannot find for the life of me, a solution.

Answer (score 2):

If you use a rich text edit field (the advanced text field available for work item definitions,  with coloring buttons and so on), you can include hyperlinks, also to other workitems etc. This is however a manual exercise to make the hyperlink point to the correct item, there is no automatic recognition of #-tags or whatever to refer to other workitems.

Comment: When you say you can add a hyperlink - how does it link to another work item? Do I have to put a full html link in there - ie it links to the sharepoint site? Or, is there a way to directly reference the ticket, so that the link will "work" within Visual Studio?

Answer (score 1):

Hi you could use a plugin called TFS Extensions Kit. TEK workitem. This is a Visual Studio extension that allows, besides other features, to open, in Visual Studio, workitems and queries from a Hyperlink.

So you could use the hyperlinks in any field. 
Look at the Visual Studio Gallery:[TFS Extensions Kit. TEK workitem](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/1397f185-7f49-49c8-ad80-e45fc9dbbfe9)

You can download a demo from [here](http://ezien.com/en/features-workitem/)

Regrads

Answer (score 1):

It's an old question, but if you get here looking for the answer for VSTS the answer is hashtag followed by itemId. Similar to @UserName to reference another user.

Eg. In comments box typing `This is a dupe of #2428` will translate into `This is a dupe of User Story 2428: Story name` where `User Story 2428: Story name` is a link to the item.

Comment: This would be in the latest versions right? Back then in TFS, we didn't even have a web interface. :)

Comment: Yep @Coopernick. Not sure what it is actually called! VSTS, VSO...?